# Flask displaying response in cmd but not in view

Tags: python, flask

I am reviewing this repository https://github.com/ibrahim4529/flask-chatbot to get an inspiration and see how a model can be deployed in a chat UI. I am able to do this in Flask but ran across a quirky situation that I am not sure how to resolve. The UI accepts the first initial message that I type, but when I try returning the response, I get an 'undefined' appended to every line that is supposed to be the bot's response. On CMD though, my function is returning response. I've provided screenshots below:

[image: cmd and UI]

Here is my routing:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/ask', methods={'POST', 'GET'})
def ask():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = (request.form['messageText'])
        bresponse = response(message)
        return render_template('Index.html', bresponse=bresponse)
```

'response' is a function that spits out the response of the model (this is the 'Rrraawwwwg!' response from the input).

Below is the js that I reviewed from the link that I am using:

```
 $('#chatbot-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var message = $('#messageText').val();
            $(".media-list").append('<li class="media"><div class="media-body"><div class="media"><div style = "text-align:right; color : #2EFE2E" class="media-body">' + message + '<hr/></div></div></div></li>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "/ask",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    $('#messageText').val('');
                    var answers = response.answers;
                    const chatPanel = document.getElementById("chatPanel");
                    $(".media-list").append('<li class="media"><div class="media-body"><div class="media"><div style = "color : white" class="media-body">' + answers + '<hr/></div></div></div></li>');
                    $(".fixed-panel").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(".fixed-panel")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
```

I am not sure what I am missing. I am seeing the response in the cli, but seeing an undefined in the UI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: error in which line, try ` $(".media-list").append("""....""")`

Comment: i just cloned the repo you shared and its working for me

Comment: I will try that. 'answers' is the variable that is not being returned in the UI. All I get is 'undefined.'

Comment: thanks @Karacken. I didn't clone it. I used a different model to do the learning. I needed the inspiration for the UI. That's where I got stuck :(

Comment: you have to change the response mode, you don't want to return a rendered template in this case, you need some json here. Otherwise you can render a section that the JS will append directly

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to make this work. I've updated ajax to below:

```
var answers = response;
$('#messageText').val();
```

I was also printing the response function, instead of returning it; reason I am seeing the response in the console and not in the view. This was the main culprit.